# Conditional CSS through PHP

Tags: php, css, conditional-statements

Should this code work? In fact, it doesn't. And I don't know why.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
         $mobile_agents = '!(tablet|pad|mobile|phone|symbian|android|ipod|ios|blackberry|webos)!i';
    if(preg_match($mobile_agents, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/css/firefox.css' type='text/css' />";
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what exactly is not working how? This is very unclear.

Comment: You have an `<?php echo` in a string.... just concatenate your base url.

Comment: You have two >'s in the echo section. One after baseurl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your echoing is done incorrectly:

```
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/css/firefox.css' type='text/css' />";
```

There is no such thing as wrapping an echo in another echo. Concatenate instead:

```
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $this->baseurl ."'/templates/css/firefox.css' type='text/css' />";
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry. I may not explain it clear enough, but your answer was great.